# QEMU exited unexpectedly with exit code -1, stderr: qemu-system-x86_64: Unknown Error

Tags: terminal, homebrew, qemu, podman

Getting while running the podman command "podman machine start" in Mac M1.

Version Details

Mac version: 12.6

Podman version: 4.2.1

Qemu version: 7.1.0

Install Podman and QEMU by using Homebrew.

Please help in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issues with OS architecture. Change your OS architecture to **arm64** with the below command, before installing the Podman and Qemu.

```
env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh --login
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @Harpz helped me, but from his comment one could understand that you need to completely re-install podman, which was not the case for me. I just needed to remove the existing podman machine. Here's what I did:

```bash
$ env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh --login
$ podman machine rm --force
$ podman machine init
$ podman machine start
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got a new M1 laptop and transferred all files from the old one. I had to reset the podman machine with:

```
$ podman machine rm --force
$ podman machine init
$ podman machine start
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have installed the x86 version of podman. Install the latest arm version.

[Podman](https://podman-desktop.io/downloads)